# Evaluation of the Poisson distribution parameter and its uncertainties using only one observation

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

I heard that, for example, the number of meteorites that hit the Earth follows the Poisson distribution. My question is how to estimate the Poisson parameter $\lambda$ and confidence interval for this estimation if we have only one observation.

Let's propose that we observe that for the period of 100 years we observed 4 meteorites.
How can we now estimate $\lambda$ and 90% c.i.'s for that observation?

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? From your question, I get the impression that you mean "estimate"?

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer if you ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @joriki Yes, "estimate" is a correct word, I changed the formulation of the problem.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks, I'll try.